# Cleaner way to use re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I know there must be a better way to accomplish the following.
Here is my function:

```
def authenticated_url(url):
    return re.sub(r"(^https://)", "https://" + access_token() + "@", url)
```

`access_token()` returns a token as a String, for example `"1248jkdfhjksabcd382"`

Desired output would be as follows:

```
>>> url = "https://github.com/jfach/autostager"
>>> auth_url = authenticated_url(url)
>>> url
'https://1248jkdfhjksabcd382@github.com/jfach/autostager'
```

That is the output I currently get, so it works, but I can't help think that I'm using the `re` module incorrectly/inefficiently.

Comment: You probably don´t need regular expressions at all, just string slices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pattern is fixed, you can do the following:

```
url[:8] + access_token() + '@' + url[8:]
```

If you're not sure about the protocol, you can use `replace`:

```
url.replace('github', access_token() + '@github')
```

Comment: It's possible the OP wants `if url.startswith('https://')` in there, based on the original way they had it. It's also possible that was an unintended side effect of their use of re.sub.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
>>> url = "https://{access_token}@github.com/jfach/autostager"
>>> url.format(access_token=access_token())
'https://1248jkdfhjksabcd382@github.com/jfach/autostager'
```